# Getting the Error "Expression does not produce a value"

Tags: vb.net

Im sorry if this is bad, but im really new to to VB, and i would like to get some help.

Here is my code,

```
Module Module1

Sub Main()
    Do Until FileClose()
        Console.WriteLine("Please choose a something between * - / -+--")
        Dim test As String = Console.ReadLine

        If test = "*" Then
            Console.WriteLine("Please choose a number to multiply.")
            Dim num1 As Integer = Console.ReadLine
            Console.WriteLine("Please choose another number to multiply it with.")
            Dim num2 As Integer = Console.ReadLine
            Console.WriteLine("The answer is " & num1 * num2)
            Console.ReadKey()
        End If
        If test = "/" Then
            Console.WriteLine("Please choose a number to Divide.")
            Dim num1 As Integer = Console.ReadLine
            Console.WriteLine("Please choose another number to Divite it with.")
            Dim num2 As Integer = Console.ReadLine
            Console.WriteLine("The answer is " & num1 / num2)
            Console.ReadKey()
        End If
        If test = "+" Then
            Console.WriteLine("Please choose a number to add.")
            Dim num1 As Integer = Console.ReadLine
            Console.WriteLine("Please choose another number to add it with.")
            Dim num2 As Integer = Console.ReadLine
            Console.WriteLine("The answer is " & num1 + num2)
            Console.ReadKey()
        End If
        If test = "-" Then
            Console.WriteLine("Please choose a number to subtract.")
            Dim num1 As Integer = Console.ReadLine
            Console.WriteLine("Please choose another number to subtract it with.")
            Dim num2 As Integer = Console.ReadLine
            Console.WriteLine("The answer is " & num1 - num2)
            Console.WriteLine("If you would like to reset this calculator, please press the R button.")
            Dim test2 As String = Console.ReadLine
            If test2 = "R" Then

            End If
            Console.ReadKey()
        End If
    Loop

End Sub

End Module
```

It says "Expression does not produce a value" for the the `FileClose()` in `Do Until FileClose()`

How can i fix this issue?

Comment: We can't determine that without knowing what the FileClose() method is doing.

Comment: Please explain what you're trying to do. Like the error says the `FileClose()` method doesn't return anything, therefore there's nothing for the loop to check against. Please read the [`FileClose()` documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.visualbasic.filesystem.fileclose) for information on how to use it correctly.

Comment: @StephenWrighton it's an old VB6 method that exists purely for backwards compatibility. It is used to close a file opened by the respective [`FileOpen()` method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.visualbasic.filesystem.fileopen).

Comment: [FileClose](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.visualbasic.filesystem.fileclose?view=netframework-4.7.2) doesn't return a value.

Comment: Presumably your intention was to check whether a file is closed or the like but I can't see where you're opening a file so why would that even be a good idea?  In plain English, what condition do you want to test?

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing that you want to keep looping until the user wants to exit the program. I would suggest altering your code so that it looks like the following

```
Dim test As String
Do
    Console.WriteLine("Please choose a something between * - / -+-- or type ""exit"" to end the program")
    test = Console.ReadLine
    'rest of your code
Loop Until test = "exit"
```